# Open gradle.build file for using CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to use the `RecyclerView` and `CardView` widgets in my app. According to the tutorials on the web, I should add these Gradle dependencies to my `gradle.build` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

My question is: where is this file? I tried to search it in my app folder but I found nothing.

Comment: Are You using gradle (https://www.gradle.org/) as Your build tool/system? If so which version?

Comment: i dont know how to check this

Comment: if you are using Android Studio then you are using gradle if Eclipse then not ... in tutorials/documentation is pointed how to add cardview and recyclerview support in eclipse ... but as AndroidStudio become stable you should consider to move your project to new build env(and IDE)

Comment: So if i work with Eclipse i should import library for using the widgets?

Comment: Try to finds jars and add them to libs folder

Comment: ... jar is not enough for cardview library in eclipse (as it use resources too)... you need to import cardview library project with resources and add it as dependencies in your project

Comment: I found tutorial of using RecyclerView and CardView in Eclipse look here : http://happilycoded.com/blog/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-eclipse-adt/

Answer (score 0):

This file is downloaded from maven central by internet and saved to your local maven (as usually in system users dir)

Comment: It isn't correct. This files are updated with the sdk manager and are stored in you sdk's folder:sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti for android files this folder is maven actually

Answer (score 0):

These files downloaded from internet, if you want exact location of these libraries then try the below location may be this can help you to find out:

YourProjectFolder\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0

In this location you can find classes.jar and manifest and res folder etc..

Comment: Thanks man!!!. But i understand that this gradle.build file is only in Android Studio and i use Eclipse

Comment: It isn't correct. This files are updated with the sdk manager and are stored in you sdk's folder:sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/.